# Dynamic selection of HTML select tag in laravel5.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5

Let's have a select tag of months of a year

```
<label name="month">Select Month</label>
<select class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
```

How can I set the current month number dynamically ? e.g. If it is May then '5' will be selected automatically. However user can also select a month manually with the help of drop down option.I want to use it in my laravel5.0 application.

Comment: If you are using jQuery: `$('select').val( (new Date).getMonth() + 1 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need use [JavaScript getMonth() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp).

If you do not use `JQuery`, try

```
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
document.getElementByClass("form-control").value = month;
```

Thanks for the comment of Erfan, we need `+1` for the value of `month`.

**Note**: In `getMonth()`, 0=January, 1=February etc.

Comment: parenthesis is missing and '1' need to add with month.
var month = date.getMonth();
document.getElementByClass("form-control").value = month+1;

Comment: again you've missed the parenthesis () of date.getmonth()   :p

Answer (score 1):

Use carbon to found the month number, than create some logic to select the right option:

```
$current_month = Carbon::now()->month;
```

There are a lot of ways to fill your select, here is a very simple one:

```
for($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {
    $selected = $m == $current_month ? 'selected' : null;
    echo '<option value="'.$m.'" '.$selected.'>'.$m.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Vohaman , try this

```
$('select').val( (new Date).getMonth() + 1 );
```